# ∀x ∈R, ∃y ∈R s.t ∀z ∈R , x + y = z

Tags: logic

∀x ∈R, ∃y ∈R s.t  ∀z ∈R , x + y = z

The above statement is false but I can't figure out why?
Or how can I prove that the statement is false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $x := 0$; if $y \in \mathbb{R}$, then $x+y = y$, which cannot be equal to every real number.

If you are not familiar with a formal statement, translate it to plain English (say); in this case, the statement is equivalent to "for every real number $x$ we can find some real number the sum of which and $x$ equals any real number", and its falsehood is crystal clear.